# How to get around unexpected keyword arguments when callsite uses keyword argument but API uses unnamed arg?

Tags: python

I have a class with a method

```
def method(self, keyarg1, keyarg2):
  # definition
```

At the callsite, it uses keyword arguments when passing in the arguments, i.e.,

```
class_instance.method(keyarg1=..., keyarg2=...)
```

I'm trying to write a mockclass with `method`, where `keyarg1, keyarg2` aren't used, so I wrote it as follows:

```
class MockedClass:
  def method(self, _, __):
    # definition
```

However, this causes issues at the callsite since the client passes in the arguments using `keyarg1=, keyarg2=`. What is the canonical way in python to get around this issue?

I could, of course, define `method` in `MockedClass` to take in `keyarg1, keyarg2`, but I will run into linter errors that I will have to silence and would prefer avoiding that route.

Comment: Why are you not simply using `**kwargs`?

Comment: @tripleee I'm a python noob and didn't know that could be used for this purpose

Answer (score 1):

You can use a dummy `kwargs`-argument, which absorbs all keyword-arguments not explicitly given in the method signature:

```py
class MockedClass:
  # Notice `**__`, which is a kwargs named `__`
  def method(self, *_, **__):
    # definition

MockedClass().method(now_hear_this='Foobar!')
```

Comment: is it better to use `**kwargs` rather than enumerating each arg like in your example?

Comment: @24n8, what do you mean "enumerating earch arg" ?

Comment: I mean instead of `def method(self, *_, **__):` can I do `def method(self,  **kwargs):`

Comment: Yes, the `**__` and `**kwargs` are equivalent. The identifier `__` is just by convention to indicate to the reader that we accept but purposefully throw away all arguments given via keywords. Same goes for `*_`.

Comment: hmm these methods both result in "Parameters differ from overriden 'method' method' linter errors or "kwargs is unused". I may have to just use the original arg names and silence the linter errors